# MAMP Cloud Function Version 4.4

Tags: localhost, mamp

Updated MAMP to the lates version 4.4 and now everything is cloud based.

Seems to me like here is no way to use the local server in the free version. To use the cloud function i have to connect to Dropbox and then pay for MAMPs cloud service.

I guess i can just start paying for there service, but i was wondering if anyone else have tried the latest update and experienced the same thing.

Maybe there is a work around to still run my local sever without using the MAMPs cloud function that i missed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MAMP 4.4 is working normal like before! The cloud function just makes it possible to save your local stuff to Dropbox and load it back from another computer. MAMP itself works locally!

Comment: Thanks! I worked it out. Was just a bit confused when my preferences was changed in to an cloud icon.

Comment: is there a way to exclude the root directory and website files? I use git for all that and some sites are 10gb plus!

Comment: No there is no way at the moment. We (MAMP team) are thinking about it. Since we have only one user with this request, its not prio 1